# Rolling Average last 28 days, but return data for yesterday

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get rolling average, but only get results for yesterday.

```
tablename['avg'] = tablename.groupby(columns)['value'].apply(
                   lambda x: x.shift().rolling(min_periods=3,window=28).mean())
```

Above gets me the rolling average, and i can filter for yesterday after this, but it takes long time to process. Is there way to change above that way it only calculates for yesterday

Sample Data

```
   day  column1 column2 column3 column4 Number
6/1/2016    group1  brian   LA  Book    500
6/1/2016    group1  john    LA  Book    455
6/2/2016    group1  John    LA  Book    650
6/2/2016    group1  brian   LA  Book    633
6/3/2016    group1  John    LA  Book    200
6/3/2016    group1  brian   LA  Book    1500
…                   
7/10/2016   group1  John    LA  Book    200
7/10/2016   group1  brian   LA  Book    200
7/11/2016   group1  John    LA  Book    1500
7/11/2016   group1  brian   LA  Book    870
```

Comment: Can you filter your input dataframe down to yesterday - 28 to yesterday then use groupby and rolling?  Not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: yes, i can filter dataframe to include yesterday and -28 days, but rolling does average for yesterday, and all other days as well. i just need average for yesterday, to improve calculation speed i wanted to not calculate for other days

Comment: You just want a scalar number for the average of the last 28 days?  Filter your dataframe down to yesterday and -28 days then .mean()

Comment: I think i can do mean() for -28 days then join yesterday's data, but i kind of loses min_periods=3  threshold from rolling, is there way to adjust rolling method to do just for yesteday?